# I'm trying to fetch data on SwiftUI from Airtable but its not working as i want to

Tags: swift, swiftui

i'm kind of a beginner on Swift. I'm trying to call an API from Airtable. For the moment the table is a simple table with title and image, and this is my JSON

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "id":"rec8zBBNAv0JyK9pu",
         "createdTime":"2022-10-31T12:28:14.000Z",
         "fields":{
            "title":"L'école du Bien et du Mal",
            "image":"imageEcole"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"recGwK28a3a8kRaeB",
         "createdTime":"2022-10-31T12:28:15.000Z",
         "fields":{
            "title":"A l'Ouest, rien de nouveau",
            "image":"imageOuest"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So i'm using a responseDTO:

```
struct ResponseDto: Decodable {
    let records: [RecordDto]
    
    struct RecordDto: Decodable {
        let id: String
        let createdTime: String
        let fields: FieldsDto
    }
    
    struct FieldsDto: Decodable {
        let title: String
        let image: String
    }
    
}
```

I also have a regular Film struct :

```
struct Film: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let image: String
}
```

and how i call it

```
class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    @Published var films = [Film]()
    
    func fetchUsers() async {
        
        // 1 - Url to fetch
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appMl82aryE3VlpSx/Series") else {
            return
        }
        
        // 2 - Create the request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        // 2.1 - Set the request method
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        // 2.2 - Set the request header : authorization token
        request.setValue(
            "Bearer mykey",
            forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"
        )
        
        // 3 - Create the task to run
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                // handle error
                print(error)
            } else if
                let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200 {
                
                do {
                    // Decode JSON response
                    let response: ResponseDto = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseDto.self, from: data)
                    
                    // Empty data before filling it again
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.films = []
                    }
                    
                    // Map dto to country and send it to main thread
                    for record in response.records {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.films.append(
                                Film(title: record.fields.title, image: String(record.fields.image))
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    // Handle error
                    print(error)
                }

            }
            
        }
        
        // 4 - Launch the task
        task.resume()
        
    }

}
```

This time i have this error :

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "records", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "fields", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Some help would be great, i'm kind of stuck since hours ! Thanks :)

I tried almost everything, with other objects, trying to find the error on SO or internet but didnt find what i was looking for.`

Comment: Some of the value is nil. Check it properly or define CodingKeys optional with a set default value.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The thing is, i dont get where CodingKeys comes from ...

Comment: coddingkeys means *fields*, *title*,

Comment: The Swift compiler itself does quite a bit of awesome work when it comes to coding and encoding, i.e. using types conforming to `Codable` and `Encodable`. `CodingKeys` is an artefact which is created by the compiler, unless you define it yourself in your types which you want to conform to `Codable`. Generally, the compiler itself makes your life a lot easier in this respect. You might read Apple's official doc: `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey`. Then also highly recommend `https://www.hackingwithswift.com`, `https://www.swiftbysundell.com` **many more** ;)

Comment: When you look closely on the error "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))", this means, you declared a field "title" which requires a (non-optional) value, a String (`let title: String`) but the encoding function did not find a value for this field in the JSON. You might declare it as "optional", aka `let title: String?`.

Comment: Hello CouchDev, thanks for your time and the answer. I tried to declare it as optional but now i have an other error "fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". So i assume my code doesnt find the title or image. But thats why i'm confuse, because my JSON is giving me a title or an image.

Comment: Yes, now the "semantic" comes into place. Your DTO now _allows_ to have this field as an optional. Your Domain Logic elsewhere must of course adhere to the same rules. Actually, it would be your "domain logic" which determines whether the field can be optional or must be mandatory. If it is mandatory, you would declare a mandatory field in the DTO. However, "shit happens", and the server would not adhere to the rules and simply "forget" it. In this case, you need to implement error handling. ;)

Comment: I just understood what you were trying to tell me, it took me some time and testing but it has to be given a mandatory value and now its working ! Thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 0):

We already mentioned your issue with Encoding/Decoding.

One bigger issue, though, is how you defined your function:

`func fetchUsers() async { ... }`

Here, you are using Swift Concurrency's async/await syntax.

Your implementation however uses (legacy) "Completion handler" approach:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
        with: request
    ) { data, response, error in
       ... 
    }
    ...
}
```

Generally, you cannot mix and match async/await style with completion handler style, without additional measurements.

What you need to do, is to convert your Completion handler style to async style. Here is the canonical approach:

Given, a completion handler style async function:

```
func legacyFetchValue(
    param: Param, 
    completion: @escaping (Result<Value, Error>) ->Void
) -> Void {
    ...
}
```

Now, you want it to convert to a modern async/await style:

`func fetchValue(param: Param) async throws -> Value`

You can achieve this as shown below:

```
func fetchValue(
    param: Param
) async throws -> Value {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        legacyFetchValue(param: param) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                continuation.resume(returning: value)
            case .failure(let error):
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the "key" is, to use `withCheckedThrowingContinuation(:)` or "friends".

There are a couple variants, which you want to use. I want you to point to the official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)

but also, to a really great tutorial, which explains it in much detail:

https://wwdcbysundell.com/2021/wrapping-completion-handlers-into-async-apis/

Comment: My school showed me the method I used above, that's why I started with this one. Thanks to your advice I was able to post what I wanted. I will definitely look at the documentation you provided and practice on it. I thank you again for the time you gave me and for your help, it was a great help

Comment: Actually, your function `fetchUsers` will work in the current context. However, the function is declared as `async` where it is actually a "fire & forget" - where the "side effect" is to update the published value. This is a usual pattern when using ObservableObjects.  However, this `async` is confusing. Just remove the `async` from `fetchUser` and it will be clear. Also, consider making this function "private". Maybe, some random client (a view maybe) should not "command" the model what to do, instead only messaging what happened to it, and then the model takes actions accordingly.